# Taking derivative of a function containing random variable wrt the variance of that variable

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, derivative

Say, I have a function containing a random variable such as $ f(X)$, where $X $ is the random variable that comes from a family of random variables that differ only in the first and second moments (e.g. family of normal curves). Is it meaningful to understand how the moments of $ f(X)$ change when the a moment of $X $ changes, holding other moments of $X $ constant?

Comment: Welcome to CV. It's hard to make sense of this, because $X$ is just "a random variable."  What could it mean to change its variance?  Evidently that would change $X$ into another random variable $Y$, but the concept of "derivative" requires that you be able to induce *arbitrarily small* changes in some well-defined sense.  We therefore need more information just to get started understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: OP: Does the distribution for $X$ have a scale parameter? If so, you could consider whether the partial derivative of the expectation of $f(X)$ with respect to that scale parameter is well-defined. This can sometimes be made easier by using the law of the unconscious statistician.